# Convert desktap app to UWP Windows 10 app

Tags: uwp, windows-10, desktop, desktop-bridge

I have a project to convert a Windows Desktop App to Windows 10 UWP App. I saw that I can use Desktop Bridge for that. I'm not sure it's compatible with my project. I have several executables that communicate between them. Is it ok with that ?

Thank you for your help.
Kind regards,
Florient.

Comment: Normal IPC is totally fine for Desktop Bridge.

Answer (score 1):

To convert your desktop app to UWP, you should know the advance preparation before you package your desktop app. See the details in the [Prepare to package an app (Desktop Bridge)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-prepare).

There is an item that describes that, you can compare with your app:

> **Your app exposes GAC assemblies for use by other processes.** In the current release, your app cannot expose GAC assemblies for use by processes originating from executables external to your Windows app package. Processes from within the package can register and use GAC assemblies as normal, but they will not be visible externally. This means interop scenarios like OLE will not function if invoked by external processes.

Please check your app with all the preparations in above topic.

On the other hand, you can try to follow the document [Package an app by using Visual Studio (Desktop Bridge)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net) to package your app to see whether you app can be converted.